# Massive PHP/MySQL insert with overlapping times

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on this software for a gym that has overlapping times for schedules, if the time is greater than 35 minutes between the end time of a class and the start time of the class, that time is dropped.

Example: I work from 8:00am to 9:00am, 8:30am to 9:30am, 10:10am to 11:10am. Anything over a 35min gap is considered a different shift.

I have this working on pay reports at this point only per employee.

The problem is that they would like to mass check-in everyone on holidays and my brain is going a bit crazy trying to figure out how to do arrays and loops on individual employee IDs, figuring out the overlap, dropping the >35min and inserting that shift into the check_ins table.

I've isolated the workers for the given holiday at this point and have the shifts they're scheduled for, I have a total number of employee IDs in an array and a total number of schedules in an array.

anyone have an idea how this might be most easily implemented without me drinking myself stupid? (If a gym ever asks you to write scheduling software, RUN!)

Thanks!

Edit: The holiday pay conditions are as variable as the friggin wind, so no help there.

My code for a single employee:

```
    //init our arrays
    $timeStart = array();
    $timeEnd = array();
    $x = 0;
    $maxInterval = new DateTime('00:35');
    $classIDArray = array();

    do {
//Get our start times for Monday
$p = new DateTime($row_GetMonSchedule2['Start_time']);
$q = new DateTime($row_GetMonSchedule2['End_time']);
$timeStart[$x] = $p->format('H:i');
$timeEnd[$x] =  $q->format('H:i');
//Get Class IDs
$classIDArray[$x] = $row_GetMonSchedule2['Class_ID'];

$totalEndTimes = count($timeEnd);
$x++;

} while ($row_GetMonSchedule2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($GetMonSchedule2));

//echo $totalRows_GetMonSchedule2;

//Now let's check the durations and make our shifts

//echo "Class ID Array: "; print_r($classIDArray);

$x = 0;
$s = 1;

do {
///First Time Start 
if ($x == 0) {
$TimeDayStart = $timeStart[$x];
}

if ($x < $totalEndTimes) {
///Last Time End
$TimeDayEnd = $timeEnd[$x]; 
}


  $x++; $s++;
} while ($x < $totalEndTimes);

$x = 0;
$s = 1;

/////Get Durations

$interval = array();


do {
 if ($x == 0) {
  //The very first end time
  //First end time of the first time block
  $firstEndTime = new DateTime($timeEnd[$x]); 
  $startTime = new DateTime($timeStart[$s]);
  $timeDiff = $startTime->diff($firstEndTime);
  $interval[$x] = $timeDiff->format('%H:%i');
 } else {
  //We don't need the last record because there isn't anything to calculate it aginst, so increase $x by one
  if ($x + 1 > $totalEndTimes) {



  } else {
    $endTime = new DateTime($timeEnd[$x]);
    $startTime = new DateTime($timeStart[$s]);
    $timeDiff = $endTime->diff($startTime);
    $interval[$x] = $timeDiff->format('%H:%i');

  }

 }



  $x++; $s++;

} while ($x < $totalEndTimes);

//Let's try to break this up into shifts now...
$x =0;
$y =0;
$zz = 1;
$s = 1;
$timeBreak =0;
$durCount = count($interval) - 1;
$BreakStartTimes = array();
$BreakEndTimes = array();
$xx3 = 0;
$yy3 = 0;

//Setup table
do {


  if ($x == 0) {
//echo $timeStart[$x]." - ";
$BreakStartTimes[$yy3] = $timeStart[$x];
$yy3++;
  if (new DateTime($interval[$x]) > new DateTime('00:35')) {
  //echo $timeEnd[$x]." ";
  $BreakEndTimes[$xx3] = $timeEnd[$x];
  $xx3++;
  $timeBreak = 1;
  //echo "Time Break";
  }

  } 
  if (new DateTime($interval[$x]) > new DateTime('00:35') && $timeBreak != 1) {
  //echo $timeEnd[$x]." ";
  $BreakEndTimes[$xx3] = $timeEnd[$x];
  $xx3++;
  $timeBreak = 1;
  //echo "Time Break";
  }

  if ($timeBreak == 1 && $x + 1 < $totalEndTimes) {
  //echo $timeStart[$s]." - ";
    $BreakStartTimes[$yy3] = $timeStart[$s];
    $yy3++;
  $timeBreak = 0;
  }


  $x++; $s++;

} while ($x < $totalEndTimes);

if (empty($BreakEndTimes)) {
  //echo "empty";
  $ttt = count($timeEnd) - 1;
  //echo $ttt;
}
```

Comment: What data specifically are you trying to retrieve? How many "shifts" each person worked?

Comment: The duration worked, omitting the start time of an overlapping schedule. If the start time of the next shift is greater than 35min, drop that 35 minutes and consider the next shift. if less than or equal to 35, consider the next scheduled time to be part of the entire shift... for 200+ unique employees... And drink another beer.

Comment: Dude you're blowing my mind. So basically you need to combine overlapping shifts into one big shift with a start time and end time. What do you mean by "drop that 35 minutes"? If it's less than 35 then do you still count that as time worked?

Comment: lol, I know... Yes. I actually have this working on an individual employee basis... I just need to do a mass check-in for holiday pay for them. I need to break this up per employee and shift and build hidden input to toss the stuff to the insert code. Like I said, if a Gym asks you to write a "Time Clock" software, they're asking for something that ain't a DAMN thing like a time clock.

Comment: What's wrong with looping through all the employees and then doing it for each employee, since you have that working?

Comment: My brain, I guess. I'm not sure I can loop through schedule_recurring, grab all the start and end times, segregate every one per Employee_ID, figure out the insane overlap and time gap and then output it to hidden fields for input.

Comment: A bunch of nested while loops should do the trick. I recommend trying to visualize it all in some way, like making a drawing. Once you know what you need to do, it shouldn't be too hard to do that in PHP. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Like some commenters have said before me, nesting some loops should do the trick. Try writing it down in pseudo code and fill in the details from there.

Example:

```
//connect to database
$conn = new mysqli("host","user","pass","db");

// check for connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) 
{
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//query for all employees working the holiday
// I might be way off with the query seeing as I don't know the complexity
$sql = "SELECT e.ID, count(s.Start_Time) FROM employee e, schedule s 
        WHERE count(s.Start_Time) >= 1 AND e.ID = s.Employee_ID
            AND s.Start_Time >= '2013-12-24 00:00:00.0000' 
            AND s.End_Time <= '2014-01-02 00:00:00.0000'
        GROUP BY e.ID;";

//get the result from database like you do already

//then do the loop
for each employee 
{
    execute the code you have for the current employee
}
do clean up or other tasks after the loop is done
```

Now this is pretty easy to start expanding and hopefully give an idea you can build on.